# FirebaseMessagingService cannot be cast to android.app.Service

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app crashes upon receiving notifications via FCM with the error "Unable to instantiate service ...: java.lang.ClassCastException: ... cannot be cast to android.app.Service"

I am implementing android app notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging as per [manual](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client). I double checked that everything is done properly as per manual and saw somehow related stackoverflow questions, however still cannot resolve the problem :( My both build.gradle files are up to date as per manual.

Before debug, AndroidManifest file highlights the error at the line com.exa.myproject.unsorted.NotificationService:

```
        <service
        android:name="com.exa.myproject.unsorted.NotificationService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

saying that com.exa.myproject.unsorted.NotificationService "must extend android.app.Service".

However in the service file, it already inherits:

```
class NotificationsService : FirebaseMessagingService()
```

Whereas FirebaseMessagingService should in turn inherit from Service per se.
Nevertheless, the app compiles and runs fine.
However, when I send test notification from FCM Firebase Console, the app crashes (obviously received message relates to background NotificationService) and is not happy to be cast to the Android Service:

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.exa.myproject, PID: 30746
java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to instantiate service com.exa.myproject.unsorted.NotificationService: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.exa.myproject.unsorted.NotificationService cannot be cast to android.app.Service**
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:232)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.exa.myproject.unsorted.NotificationService cannot be cast to android.app.Service
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:232) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30746 SIG: 9

Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't allow the classes to be inherited from 2 classes simultaneously. Otherwise I would inherit NotificationService from Service also apart from FirebaseMessagingService.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, so it was a dummy situation.
As a result of multiple merges, 2 copies of the same file was created. So eventually I had in the repository 2 services (2 Kotlin classes):

- NotificationService
- NotificationSService
  Only one of them was referenced in the AndroidManifest file. That was improper one.
  So eventually I removed the improper file, referenced the proper one and now it works.
  The lesson for me is in case of bug to track all the chain way of all the references, especially those going outside of the class, outside of the file. Compiler doesn't always show the direct root cause of the problem...